# Automated function hints tool in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have worked shortly with Netbeans using Java and use eclipse for school projects, where I noticed there are some really cool features like it will show built-in functions on ctrl-space or it will suggest from existing variables. I recently started using matlab, I was wondering if there are any such tools available in the matlab. I know it's a scripting environment so things are probably a little different but then I wonder people who work with extensive projects with matlab, how would they manage the codes or cross-develop without such tools.  I searched mathworks but could not find any useful information on that.
Anyone knows if such tools or add-ons existe for matlab? Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: `tab` will autocomplete variables and load a dropdown for different functions, but I believe it doesn't work for fields.  I definitely agree that it is annoying switching between eclipse and Matlab, so I would also appreciate anything more in depth.

Comment: Which other features besides autocomplete you feel are lacking?

Comment: @Salain: autocomplete certainly works for fields. The only limitation I noticed is that this only works with the variables in your current workspace. So if you are editing an object in MATLAB and are self-referencing it using the name `obj`, it really pays to have such an object in your workspace.

Comment: @Salain Thanks! Did not know about tab autompletes and shows all different functions. For now thats all I need.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before, autocomplete works for functions, variables and fields.

If it seems to fail to work for a field (perhaps because your workspace is not properly set up) it can help to call the field without index:

For example: 
entity.field instead of entity(i).field

Also if you change the workspace frequently it may be that the mfile editor does not catch up, in that case a quick workaround is to just type in the command window and copy afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before the variables need to be in workspace.

I often approach so that I evaluate the code as I write it like this:

- Write the code in [cell mode](http://matlab.izmiran.ru/help/techdoc/matlab_env/edit_d48.html)
- Evaluate cell with [ctrl - enter] - or button in menu bar.
- Write next cell (variables of previous blocks are now available in workplace, autocomplete with tab)

---

There is also a [matlab mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/MatlabMode) for emacs. It offers *some* autocomplete functionality and has a nice feature to wrap long code lines.

unfortunately on windows it lacks the ability to evaluate cells. So I rarely use it.

Answer (score 0):

There are some similar design in MATLAB, one of them is called function hints.

You could find the documentation for it in here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/check-syntax-as-you-type.html